# Android remove Span from SpannableString

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, spannable

My target is to remove last span from SpannableString. I have created SpannableString like this:

```
String simple = (String) label.getText();
String colored = " * ";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(simple);
int start = builder.length();
builder.append(colored);
int end = builder.length();

builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(
        getResources().getColor(R.color.red)), start, end,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

label.setText(builder);
```

How can I remove that end span?

Comment: there is a removeSpan method